# Vue js data binding doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a vue component but whenever I want to hide some elements with `v-show` it doesn't work.

When you click any element on the list I want to hide it and on the click event `element.visible` is set to false, so in the component template I bind that value to `v-show` but it wont hide.

I guess it's because `element.visible` it's kind of nested attribute but I'm not really sure.

```js
var collection = [
        { id: 1, name: 'element 1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'element 2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'element 3' },
        { id: 4, name: 'element 4' },
        { id: 5, name: 'element 5' },
        { id: 6, name: 'element 6' },
        { id: 7, name: 'element 7' },
        { id: 8, name: 'element 8' },
      ];

var multiselect = {
  props: ['collection'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      subscribed: [],
      toSubscribe: [],
      toUnsubscribe: [],
      dataset: []
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
   this.dataset = _.map(this.collection, function(element){
     element.visible = true;
      return element;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    subscribe: function(element){
   element.visible = false;
    }
  }

}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'multiselect': multiselect
  },
  data: {
    elements: collection
  }
})
```

```css
.multiselect .list {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 215px;
  max-height: 215px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.multiselect .list .list-element {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.multiselect .list .list-element:hover {
  background-color: #d6dbdf;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>



<div id="app">

  <multiselect inline-template :collection="elements">
    <div class="col-sm-12 multiselect">

      <div class="col-sm-5 list">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div v-for="element in dataset" class="list-element" @click="subscribe(element)" v-show="element.visible">
            {{element.name}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-fill">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-fill">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-5 list">

      </div>

    </div>
  </multiselect>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying an already-responsive object. [Vue cannot detect property additions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

It's obscured by the fact that you're copying via `map`, and assigning it to a new array, but it's an array of references to responsive objects, to each of which you have added the `visible` property. If you examine the data items in the parent, you'll see that it gets `visible` added, too.

The minimal fix is to use `Object.assign` to create a new object and copy properties into it. This way all properties are inserted into a non-responsive object, which is then made responsive during assignment.

```
  mounted: function(){
    this.dataset = _.map(this.collection, function(element){
      return Object.assign({}, element, {visible: true});
    });
  },
```

You *could* do this in created, since you don't need the DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

As an interesting variation, you don't need to clone the `collection` elements or set a property on them.

It is enough to have a parallel array of flag, but you have to be careful of the syntax to update them and the flag must be contained in an object in order to be observable.
i.e an array of `{ visible: true }` rather than an array of `true`.

Ref: [Mutation-Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods)

```js
var collection = [
  { id: 1, name: 'element 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'element 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'element 3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'element 4' },
];

var multiselect = {
  props: ['collection'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      visibleFlags: []
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    this.collection.forEach(x => {
      this.visibleFlags.push({visible: true});  // Vue mutation method
    })
  },
  methods: {
    subscribe: function(index){
      this.$set(this.visibleFlags, index, false)
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'multiselect': multiselect
  },
  data: {
    elements: collection
  }
})
```

```css
.multiselect .list {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 125px;
  max-height: 215px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.multiselect .list .list-element {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.multiselect .list .list-element:hover {
  background-color: #d6dbdf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <multiselect inline-template :collection="elements">
    <div class="col-sm-12 multiselect">
      <div class="col-sm-5 list">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div v-for="(element, index) in collection" 
            class="list-element" v-show="visibleFlags[index].visible" 
            @click="subscribe(index)">
            {{element.name}} 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </multiselect>
</div>
```